# Filling missing data in python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, missing-data

I am developing regression ANN to predict the Total produced energy by PV, Wind offshore and Winonshore. Therefore, I am having a four different csv files and I need to make a valid dataframe. One of the file is 'weather data' which contains lot of missing values. The csv file contains following column names ''Stations_ID', 'Date', 'Minimum Temperature', 'Average Temperature','Maximum Temperature', 'relative humidity', 'Average windspeed (Beaufort)', 'Maximum windspeed (m/s)', 'sunshine duration', 'average cloud cover', 'Rain','average air preassure''

Kindly let me know How can I deal with these missing data?

Comment: What does "Deal with the missing data" mean? Can you share a sample of this CSV and what your desired results after "Dealing with the missing data" might look like?

Comment: Just listing all the column names is pointless. Please create a real example of your problem.

Comment: How would I share a CSV file here to make it more understandable?

Answer (score 0):

One easy thing done related to missing data is simply amputation, meaning remove all rows having missing data and keep only data points that have complete information.

Second, in your specific case, you may probably find open APIs providing weather data if you know the locations of the energy plants. This will help you to find approximate values of the missing data.